# How can I ensure a value in a document is still the same after insert

Tags: mongodb, .net-core

Let's say i retrieve a document and check whether Value = 3.

```
{
Value: 3
FieldToBeUpdated: "new value as long Value is 3"
}
```

Is it possible to know wether that value still holds 3 when i update the document and has not been changed from elsewhere? Or do i have to check the document again after insert and assert it is still 3?

It should not be possible to update if Value != 3. Afaik, i can't guarantee that no one else has updated it in the meantime.

I'm using MongoDB C#/.NET Driver

Comment: How are you doing the update?

Comment: I retrieve my document, does some check on the object the update on it